# Why does the following limit exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

I was doing a problem regarding infinite sums of functions, but I don't understand one thing. If we define the following functions:
$$ f_n(x)=\sin^n(x)$$
And the following inifnite series:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sin^n(x)=\frac{1}{1-\sin x}=f(x) $$
The question asks to say whether the following limit exists or not:

$$ \lim_{x\to\frac\pi2} f(x)= \lim_{x\to\frac\pi2} \frac{1}{1-\sin x} $$

To me it would seem that the limit shouldn't exist as the function goes to inifinity and/or the series diverges and so doesn't converge to a function, so its limit shouldn't exist, however the answer says it does. How can this be?

Comment: Your resoning is right. Maybe the answer has the opinion that sequences that diverge to infinity converge to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever $|\sin(x)| < 1$, the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\sin(x))^n$ will always be converging, and its limit will indeed be $\frac{1}{1-\sin(x)}$. However, if $\sin(x)=1$ then the geometric series diverges (it is just an infinite sum of ones!).

This, in particular, means that $f(x)$ exists and is continuous in $[0,1)$, so you can do the limit... which is, of course, $+\infty$ (this can be proved explicitly with an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument, or perhaps with a clever inequality as well)